# How can I force to load a hidden class (which is only shown via JQuery) onto mediaquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

Okay so I have this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0anpeLj0/1/) here, where you can see I have one small nav, and it changes upon scrolling. The small nav is used minimalstic as the focus is needed on the hero image; and after that the nav becomes a little bit bigger and requests a little bit more focus from the viewer.

But now upon working on my mediaqueries I want to just show the second nav for mobile users, since they cannot hover on the first nav (due to not having a mouse obviously), so they have no use for the first navigation and it's useless for them.

But I only show the second nav with the use of Jquery/JS.

```
if ($window.scrollTop() > navShiftBreakpoint) {
        $navContainer.addClass( 'full' );}
 //full = the second nav & //navShiftBreakpoint = 500px
```

I cannot force to add a class in HTML from css, so any idea on how I can fight this problem?

Thanks for the effort/help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser) script to detect if the device is mobile and if it is, avoid initiating scroll callback and directly apply hidden class.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.